# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'My-Project'

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn, digital-ocean, daemon

Running `systemctl status gunicorn.service` gives me the output:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-10-16 14:46:53 UTC; 4s ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
    Process: 61433 ExecStart=/home/myname/My-Project/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock My-Project.wsgi:application (code=exited, st>
   Main PID: 61433 (code=exited, status=3)

Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61446]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61446]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61446]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61446]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61446]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61446]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61446]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'My-Project'
Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61446]: [2020-10-16 14:46:53 +0000] [61446] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 61446)
Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61433]: [2020-10-16 14:46:53 +0000] [61433] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Oct 16 14:46:53 django-ubuntu-pleasehelpme gunicorn[61433]: [2020-10-16 14:46:53 +0000] [61433] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

The directories I’m working in are as follows.
`myapp/` has my `requirements.txt` file, my `env`, and another `app/` dir. Within `myapp/app`, I have `manage.py` and another a`p`p dir. Within `myapp/app/app`, I have `settings.py` and `wsgi.py`.

This is my settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", None)

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my.site.co.uk', 'localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'My-Project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

And this is my wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DMy-Project.settings')
sys.path.append('/home/myname/My-Project/app')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Please lmk if you need any more info - I'm new to dev.

I've tried:
[Apache/Django: ImportError: No module named 'my_project'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42566367/apache-django-importerror-no-module-named-my-project)
[Gunicorn not starting throwing gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046137/gunicorn-not-starting-throwing-gunicorn-service-failed-with-result-exit-code)
[Gunicorn/Django, ImportError: No module named application.wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616586/gunicorn-django-importerror-no-module-named-application-wsgi)

My directory:

```
My-Project
 - ./
 - ../
 - .DS_Store   
 - .git/
 - .idea/
 - .travis.yml
 - Dockerfile
 - docker-compose.yml
 - env/ ( ./    ../    bin/    include/    lib/    lib64 -> lib/    pyvenv.cfg    share/)
 - requirements.txt
 - app/ ( ./  ../  .flake8  1  db.sqlite3  env  manage.py*  static/ app/ (./ ../    __init__.py    __pycache__/ asgi.py settings.py urls.py wsgi.py))
```

Comment: please post your project directory structure screenshot. Typically ModuleNotFound in django means you didn't add a specific app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in`settings.py` so try adding `'My-Project'` at the end of that list

Comment: thanksfor commenting @quqa123, tried adding it but still getting the same error. I added the edit wit my directory to my question

Comment: well you actually don't have a module called My-Project - your "main app" is called `app` - typical convention is to call it the same as the project. so try changing `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DMy-Project.settings')` (i hope this D at the beginning is just a typo) to `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')` [link] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE) also try changing the Gunicorn settings to `app.wsgi:application` I dont guarantee this will help that why i comment instead of answering

Comment: @quqa123 now I just get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem with you.
I'm using Django version 3.1.5. Since in the Django directory structure only has these:

- manage.py
- project-name: _ _ init _ _.py, asgi.py, settings.py, urls.py, wsgi.py
- requirements.txt
- myapp.py: _ _ init _ _.py, admin.py, apps.py, models.py, tests.py, urls.py, views.py, migrations

In your wsgi.py, you forgot to import sys:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DMy-Project.settings')
sys.path.append('/home/myname/My-Project/app')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But `sys.path.append(...)` actually it's not necessary.
After that, you can test gunicorn with simple command:
`gunicorn project-name.wsgi:application --log-file -`

Eventhough it doesn't have file named project-name.wsgi, gunicorn automatically call file wsgi.py inside project-name subdirectory.

Additional info, in development mode, if you want to make static folder recognized by django, add this into urls.py inside project-name subdirectory (this the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801140/3518455):

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```